# What taxes does an Eritrean-American-Canadian citizen Canadian resident pay first?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, citizenship

I am a Canadian born to an American-born Canadian father and an Eritrean mother. We live in Canada, where I was born. I am a citizen of all three countries mentioned.

Because of insane laws, I am still required to pay taxes in the countries I don't live in but where my parents were born.

I figure I need to pay my Canadian taxes first, but I'm not 100% sure.

Assuming my Canadian taxes come first, which one comes next? Can I deduct my Eritrean taxes from my American taxes? I want to file soon so I can receive the US stimulus money. However I'm also not sure about how much of the stimulus money needs to be paid to Canada and Eritrea.

It's all a mess! Please help!

Comment: Do you hold all three citizenships?

Comment: If you made less than USD 107,000 last year you may have to file a US tax return, but you should not have to pay any US taxes. That would make the question of what you can deduct on your US taxes, or whether your US taxes can be deducted from your income before taxation by the other countries, moot.

Comment: I've made about 200,000 USD but half of it was not employment income. Such a mess!

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea yes of course, that is why I'm asking

Comment: @rashpinducknam A quick google search shows that Eritrea does not recognize dual citizenship [https://www.multiplecitizenship.com/wscl/ws_ERITREA.html#:~:text=DUAL%20CITIZENSHIP%3A%20NOT%20RECOGNIZED.,citizenship%20they%20have%20since%20acquired.]; it seems unlikely that you hold all 3 citizenships (note: the *right* to obtain Eritrean citizenship is not the same as *having* it).

Comment: Note that also for US citizenship, merely having a US parent is not necessarily sufficient criteria for that citizenship to pass to yourself. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Acquisition-US-Citizenship-Child-Born-Abroad.html#:~:text=A%20person%20born%20abroad%20in,prior%20to%20the%20person's%20birth. It seems that you are adamant about your situation but perhaps this is more hypothetical than immediate reality?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon you're going to believe some no name ancient website or my mother, an actual real-life ErItrean-Canadian? If Eritrea didn't accept dual citizenship, there would be almost no Eritreans in Canada

Comment: My dad filed papers telling the US about me when I was a kid

Comment: @rashpinducknam Eritreans in Canada either (a) give up their Eritrean citizenship when they gain Canadian citizenship; or (b) retain Eritrean citizenship while holding some other form of visa living in Canada. Not every immigrant has citizenship in their new country. Not every immigrant retains citizenship of their home country.

Comment: Also - "filed papers telling the US about me" is still not the same thing as actually currently holding US citizenship. I highly recommend you seek legal immigration advice to confirm your status in all 3 countries.